# EACCES (Permission denied) with granted permissions in API 17 (4.2)

Tags: android, permissions

I have an application that correctly works with files in "external storage".
Recently I upgrade Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3. And after this upgrade an application fails when creating files in external storage with `EACCESS (Permission denied)`.

**Affected versions**

I have error in *Android 4.0.3, 4.1, 4.2*

I do not have error in *Android 4.3, 4.4* and higher.

**Code example**

It is part of code, that fails

```
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/.tmpfile");

if (!tempFile.exists() && !tempFile.createNewFile()) {
    throw new IOException("Cannot create temp file");
}
```

And in method `createNewFile()` throws exception with `EACCES`:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
      ...
  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
      ...
  java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
      ...
  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
      at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
    ... 15 more
```

Of course, I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. 
Application have granted permissions. I check it in main activity via:

```
if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
}
```

and have `requestCode == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` is true.

**The most strange**: when I try to rollback my code to previous stable **production** releases (when files was succesfully created in 2.2) and create build, I get the same error! :( I get this error in emulator, in real devices.

Why? What was changed in Android Studio 2.3, that I cant create any file in old Android?

**UPD**
Thanks for Nick, he helps me to find difference in behaviour. I test below lines on Android 4.2 and 4.3, and get:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
4.2: '/mnt/sdcard'
4.3: '/storage/sdcard'

ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)
4.2: {null} (array with one null-element)
4.3: '/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example/files'

Environment.getExternalStorageState()
4.2: 'removed'
4.3: 'mounted'
```

Comment: Did you add permission in `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: @AndiGeeky yes, I write it in post.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. That is not on SD card. That is external storage.

Comment: Maybe you also should request the READ permission?

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for your correction (change sdcard to external storage). About READ permission - I tried. I did define it in AndroidManifest, and tried to request in runtime... and no effect. :(

Comment: @comm1x Could you please, also try MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS permission.

Comment: @GensaGames not working. Also get EACCES with it permission.

Comment: What is getExternalStorageDirectory resolving to exactly? (Does it already end in /). Have you tried with another filename (not beginning with .), if this is really an SD card it's possible dot files are restriced

Comment: @NickCardoso getExternalStorageDirectory() return '/mnt/sdcard'. With filename it == '/mnt/sdcard/.tmpfile'. Also tried other names without dot - it is not have any effect.

Comment: @NickCardoso If dot can produce problems, why code works in android since 4.3?

Comment: Android changed how you access external files from 4.4, I don't know a change for 4.3 off the top of my head. Just to be explicit, getExternalStorageDirectory logs the same resolution on 4.4 and 4.0.3? What does Environment.getExternalStorageState() tell you?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem concerns changes made in Android 4.4. To quote [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Sometimes, a device [...] may also offer an SD card slot. When such a device is running Android 4.3 and lower, the getExternalFilesDir() method provides access to only the internal partition and your app cannot read or write to the SD card

The documentation also offers a solution:

> If you'd like to access both possible locations while also supporting Android 4.3 and lower, use the support library's static method

This refers to using [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) rather than the core Android method

```
File[] dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(ctx, null); //null, no specific sub directory
if (dirs.length > 0) {
    File ext = dirs[dirs.length -1]; //Just presuming SD card will be the last one offered
    //use ext here like you used tempFile before
}
```

You should also make sure that the media is available, as lower Android versions are more likely to be using low performance devices. Do that with the Environment class

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
     //safe
}
```

**EDIT**

So a complete solution might be to replace

```
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/.tmpfile");
```

With

```
File tempFile = null;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    //compatible for ALL the versions
    File[] dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(ctx, null); //null, no specific sub directory
    if (dirs.length > 0) {
        tempFile  = dirs[dirs.length -1]; 
    }
}
if (tempFile != null) {
    //here continue exactly as you did before
    if (!tempFile.exists() && !tempFile.createNewFile()) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot create temp file");
    }
} else {
    //handle case where sd card isnt reachable (notification etc)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helps me to find difference in behaviors 4.2 and 4.3 But I still cannot understand how to fix problem? I think core of problem that state of external storage is 'removed'. What do you think?

I update topic.

Comment: But I've given you the solution (ContextCompat) have you tried that? I'll edit

Comment: Yes, and my code goes into last "else" (external storage not unreachable). But it is also my question. Why external storage became not available on all real devices and emulators with 4.0.3, 4.1, 4.2, and available on 4.3 and higher?

Comment: Ah, because the method you are using was only designed for the way 4.4 onwards accesses the file systerm, as I mentioned before, they changed the way file access worked from that version

Comment: But.. code works successfully in Android 4.3, how do you explain it? And how do you explain, that in Android Studio 2.2 project succefully works on all Android since 4.0.3?

Comment: IDE it was written in isn't relevant to whether the code works unless it compiled differently. I don't get what you are asking. Your question is about it not working on all versions, now you're saying it already does?

Comment: See again part of topic "Affected versions". I write, that problem exist only on 4.0.3, 4.1 and 4.2. Since 4.3 and higher all works fine, without any errors.

Comment: "how do you explain, that in Android Studio 2.2 project succefully works on all Android since 4.0.3" - your words

Comment: Yes, the problem appears after updating Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3. On AS 2.2 code works fine on all versions. After updating to 2.3, I get the problem of topic in Android 4.0.3, 4.1 and 4.2. And all devices with 4.3 and higher continue normal work.

Comment: Then perhaps it's possible studio automatically optimized to use the compatibility versions - but this seems *very* unlikely to me. Perhaps you missed something when testing OR you had to change support library versions when you changed studio version. Otherwise you'll have to wait for a better answer from someone who knows specifics about the changes in Android Studio.

Comment: Thank for your attention, Nick.

Comment: No Problem. Maybe google the release notes for that AS version if you're interested, I don't have spare time right now